# VS2010 Share Response Cookie Among Multiple WCF Clients to SOAP 1.1 Service

Tags: wcf, cookies, soap, basichttpbinding

I have a third-party Java web service listening at three SOAP 1.1 WSDL endpoints. One of the endpoints is used to initiate the session and perform some high-level tasks, and the other endpoints are for subject-specific tasks reusing that initial authentication.

I'm building a C# WCF application to talk to the service, and I'd like to share the session cookie among the three client objects.

What's the VS2010 'best practices' way of sharing this cookie?

If this article is still the best answer, I can go with it, but I would appreciate some additional feedback, especially if .NET 4 introduced a simplification that I'm not finding on-line.
http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/

I can pretty easily create the first client and retain the session (new BasicHttpBinding myBinding; myBinding.AllowCookies = true), but I couldn't find an elegant way of saving off the cookie from the Connect response and reusing for the two auxiliary clients.

Any insights are appreciated.

I should note that I'm aware of CookieContainer and using Add Web Reference instead of Add Service Reference. That method is labeled as 'legacy' in most posts I've read, and I'd prefer to stay current...or as current as possible when working with SOAP 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned article is still valid. You have to use OperationContextScope and access message properties to get protocol specific data. This complexity is based on the fact that WCF architecture is protocol independent whereas ASMX architecture was HTTP protocol dependent.

It is true that ASMX (WebReference) is legacy technology but it is still present in .NET framework so if you know that you will never need nothing more the basic SOAP messaging without any advanced WS-* standard you can still use it and make your life little bit simple. Once you need anything more you can still refactor your code and use WCF with mentioned code to work with cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Moving away from the ASMX method is definitely introducing unnecessary complication at this time. I'll take your advice and stick with the simple method.